# Issues with Elastic Beanstalk not picking up jobs with Active Elastic Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails application deployed to Elastic Beanstalk and I am trying to get Active Elastic Job working. There is no indication of any error, it's just not picking the request out of the SQS queue. I have a Dockerfile that looks like this

```
FROM ruby:3.1.3

WORKDIR /app

ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1
ENV PORT=3000

# For assets precompile
ARG RAILS_ENV=production
ENV RAILS_ENV=production
ARG RACK_ENV=production
ENV RACK_ENV=production

COPY . .

# Other setup...

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app_server:
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-region: ca-central-1
        awslogs-group: ${SCOPE}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-rails-app
        awslogs-create-group: "true"
    build: .
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
      - AWS_S3_BUCKET=${AWS_S3_BUCKET}
      - AWS_SECRET_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
      - BUNDLE_WITHOUT=${BUNDLE_WITHOUT}
      - BUNDLER_DEPLOYMENT_MODE=${BUNDLER_DEPLOYMENT_MODE}
      - DB_USERNAME=${RDS_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${RDS_PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME=${RDS_DB_NAME}
      - DB_HOST=${RDS_HOSTNAME}
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${RDS_USERNAME}:${RDS_PASSWORD}@${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}
      - FRONT_END_URL=${FRONT_END_URL}
      - GOOGLE_API_KEY=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}
      - RACK_ENV=${RACK_ENV}
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV}
      - RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=${RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION}
      - RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=${RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS}
      - REDIS_TLS_URL=${REDIS_TLS_URL}
      - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}
      - ROOT_URL=${ROOT_URL}
      - SENDGRID_API_KEY=${SENDGRID_API_KEY}
      - SMTP_ADDRESS=${SMTP_ADDRESS}
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=${SMTP_PASSWORD}
      - SMTP_USERNAME=${SMTP_USERNAME}
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY_BASE}
      - ENVIRONMENT_NAME=${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
      - PROCESS_ACTIVE_ELASTIC_JOBS=${PROCESS_ACTIVE_ELASTIC_JOBS}
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/worker.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - "${EB_LOG_BASE_DIR}/nginx-proxy:/var/log/nginx"
    depends_on:
      - app_server
```

Is there something I am forgetting here? I am setting the `PROCESS_ACTIVE_ELASTIC_JOBS` to true like the [documentation](https://github.com/active-elastic-job/active-elastic-job/tree/master) says to, and my queues are named correctly. The application server is pushing jobs to the queue with no problem.